# Concatenate string with multiple range?

Tags: python

I want to make string and concatenate it with range one (1, 20) and range two(2041,2055) and range two(5001,5004).

I have tried code like this:

```
["Class_"+str(i) for i in range(1,20)] + ["Class_"+str(o) for o in range(2041,2055)] + ["Class_"+str(p) for p in range(5001,5004)]
```

Maybe have another way more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps clearer is to first assemble the full list of ids, e.g.

```
ids = [*range(1, 20), *range(2041, 2055), *range(5001, 5004)]
classes = [f"Class_{i}" for i in ids]
```

---

A more memory-efficient way:

```
from itertools import chain

ids = chain(range(1, 20), range(2041, 2055), range(5001, 5004))
classes = [f"Class_{i}" for i in ids]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can factorize the common parts of the expression in a list comprehension like this:

```
[f'Class_{i}' for s,e in [(1,20),(2041,2055),(5001,5004)] for i in range(s,e) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, use plus-equals operator (`+=`):

```py
classes = [f"Class_{i}" for i in range(1, 20)]
classes += [f"Class_{o}" for o in range(2041, 2055)]
classes += [f"Class_{p}" for p in range(5001, 5004)]
```